# Drop row if some columns are empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic table in my db, that columns are altered and deleted from other scripts. Because there is a chance that all those extra columns might hold null or empty values eventually i want to have a 'cleanup' action somewhere that checks for those cells, and if all are empty, to drop the whole row.

[image]

The ones in red are the ones i want to check. If both columns are null or empty WHERE customers_id = 1, then DELETE row.

Like i said this is just an example...There could be 5 or 10 columns after customers_id. I need to check them all if they are empty. 
I can get all the names of those extra columns in a string like this:

```
$temparray = array();
$q = mydb_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE field NOT REGEXP 'id|customers_id'");
while($row = mydb_fetch_array($q)){
  $temparray[] = $row['Field'];
}
$forSQL = " '".implode("', '", $temparray)."' ";  // gives  'client_custom_contact_person', 'client_custom_password'
$forPHP = implode(", ", $temparray); //gives   client_custom_contact_person, client_custom_password
```

What is the fastest way to check if all those column values are empty to drop that row ?

Should i go with a php foreach function ? Or is there a faster mysql query i could do ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Using the $forPHP string:

```
$q2 = mydb_query("SELECT $forPHP FROM $table WHERE customers_id = 1");
            $res = mydb_fetch_assoc($q2);
            if(!array_filter($res)) {
                //If all are empty then
                mydb_query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE customers_id = 1");
            }
```